# Can I unlock my Samsung Tablet without Internet, or can I access internet while locked out?

Tags: lock-screens, tablet, locked-out, samsung-galaxy-tab

I've locked myself out of my tablet. I haven't used it since high school, and forgot the password! It's a Samsung Tab E from 2015

I was able to find all the features for Find My Mobile, since I have a Samsung account registered with the Tablet, so I could hypothetically reset my password or get rid of the lock altogether - but, my tablet isn't connected to the internet, and I can't connect until I unlock my tablet :/

So, is there a way to connect to the internet without unlocking my tablet, or unlocking my tablet without the internet? I'm open to suggestions outside those offered in Find My Mobile

Comment: provide free wifi maybe it connects automatically, or simulate old known wifi ssid + passphrase. if device is LTE version insert SIM card with mobile data enabled and SIM PIN disabled